# Make a cell active when checkbox is checked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a checkbox sitting in a cell in an Excel spreadsheet. I'm writing a macro that places text in certain cells using the `Activecell.Offset` function, like so:

```
Activecell.Offset(3,1).Value = "Needed"
```

However, to make this work as desired, I need to have the cell which contains the checkbox be made the Active cell when the box is checked. How do I do this?

Comment: You can try this on the click even for the checkbox, but it may not work well as the Checkbox will be the thing that has the focus once it's clicked: `ActiveCell = Range(CheckBox1.TopLeftCell.Address)`

Comment: Don't `Select`. And why `FormulaR1C1` when you just want to set its value? `Activecell.Offset(3,1).Value = "Needed"`

Comment: Is the checkbox an *ActiveX* control or a *Forms* control?

Comment: @Mat'sMug it's a Forms control. And changing the verbage of how I'm inserting that value doesn't really address my problem. I still need to make the checkbox the active cell so the offset will point to the correct cell.

Comment: It doesn't really address *that* problem, but looking at any of the thousand-or-so questions on this site involving run-time errors stemming from `Select` and `Activate`, I **STRONGLY** recommend you "change the verbiage of how you're inserting that value". Just sayin'.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm not saying it isn't a good suggestion, I'm just saying it's not particularly helpful in answering the question I asked.

Comment: Hence why I posted it as a comment rather than as an answer. Geez. Also you explicitly ask about how to make it "the active cell" - which points directly to that: bad idea, there's certainly a better way.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I need to check a checkbox, and upon its being checked I need to add text to cells that are located at specific distances beneath it. I can't explicitly call the cell ranges because then if rows are added above them it'll render the macro inaccurate. If you've got a better way then by all means feel free to share.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155453/discussion-between-xander-and-mats-mug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for Form Control CheckBox Object
Make sure that your index of checkbox and the index in `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1)`
are the same...

```
Sub Checkbox1_Click()
 Dim chkBox As CheckBox
 Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1)
 Range(chkBox.LinkedCell).Offset(3, 1).Value="Needed"
End Sub
```

You can also do the fill-with-`Needed` based on the value in the `LinkedCell`.

If your check box is an ActiveX Control. You can do the similar action method on it.

---

**EDITED** to show more detail

The workflow for Checkbox form control would be as below:-
 1. RightClick the check box-> Format Control
[image]
 2. Cell Link, this would typically be the cell behind the check-box, you want anchored(you can set the font color to white so that it doesn't show the values)
[image]
 3. RightClick the check box-> Assign Macro
[image]
 4. Click "New"
[image]
 5. It show create the below snippet for you

```
Sub CheckBox2_Click()

End Sub
```

6. Fill in the Sub with the code I had shown you before..

```
Sub Checkbox2_Click()
 Dim chkBox As CheckBox
 Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(2)
 Range(chkBox.LinkedCell).Offset(3, 1).Value="Needed"
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you get that to fire? I created a Form checkbox, and clicking it and uncliking it does nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to do it once for each of the checkboxes you've.

Comment: @bulbus so if I'm understanding this correctly, I have to give an index value to each checkbox in the spreadsheet in order to make this work?

Comment: When you right click assign macro on the check box, it will automatically show you the Sub name like `Checkbox2_Click`, `Checkbox3_Click`,`Checkbox4_Click`... Use the same digit/index in the line Set `chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(1)`

Comment: I've update the answer with the workflow you should follow to achieve this. See if it helps!

Comment: @Xander did the detail help you?